# Using explode but after first <br><br> Pattern

Tags: laravel

I am using explode to create an array from string and using pattern `<br><br>` but in my case i want it to be start after first match `<br><br>`. Means when first time it gets `<br><br>` then it skip and create an array from second time and so on match `<br><br>`

```
<?php
$myString = "Welcome, j.<br><br>
 
(1) this revisional application has been preferred under  read with section of the against the order  passed by the learned special judge, ndps act, 6th court at barasat.<br><br>

(2) case of the petitioner is that he along with other accused persons are facing trial case, as pending the learned additional sessions judge, 6th court. barasat.";

    $myArray = explode('<br><br>', $myString);

    // $arr = ltrim($myArray, ' ');
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($myArray);
    

    foreach($myArray as $key => $value)
    { 
            $whatIWant = substr($value, strpos($value," "));
            echo ucfirst($whatIWant);
        
    }
```

Basically my task is to Capitalize first letter of Second word i.e  this and case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_shift()` function to shift your array by one element and skip first item in your array.

[php document for array_shift](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php)

```
$myArray = explode('<br><br>', $myString);

array_shift($myArray);

foreach($myArray as $key => $value)
{ 
    $whatIWant = substr($value, strpos($value," "));
    echo ucfirst($whatIWant);      
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much but i cannot use array_shift because not in every case i want to skip first element. thats why i am looking for another approach.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using [preg_match_all](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) instead.

```
The code below looks for the pattern (\d+) (\w+)
\d+ = 1 or more digits
\w+ = 1 or more alphanumeric letters
```

If you were to add (3)... (4)... and so on, it would match all of them

```
<?php

$myString = "Welcome, j.<br><br>

(1) this revisional application has been preferred under  read with section of the against the order  passed by the learned special judge, ndps act, 6th court at barasat.<br><br>

(2) case of the petitioner is that he along with other accused persons are facing trial case, as pending the learned additional sessions judge, 6th court. barasat.";

preg_match_all("/(\(\d+\))\s(\w+)/", $myString, $all_matches);

foreach ($all_matches[1] as $idx => $match) {
    $original = "{$match} " . $all_matches[2][$idx];
    $replacement = "{$match} " . ucfirst($all_matches[2][$idx]);
    $myString = str_replace($original, $replacement, $myString);
}

echo $myString;
```